# Understanding the information in an extended class in the <> in Java?

Tags: java, hadoop

```
public static class Map extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
```

I'm developing in Java for the first time in years. I am implementing some map reduce methods in Hadoop. Can someone explain the point of the `<Text, Text, Text, Text>` in this class definition? What exactly is it doing?

```
  public static class TokenizerMapper
       extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
      while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(itr.nextToken());
        context.write(word, one);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: seems like a generic converted to `Text` type. But would be good if you could share the `Mapper` implementation. Looking into it might provide you details as well.

Comment: Map accepts Text string as input and spits out text as output, while reducer takes Text as input (that you got from map phase) and spits out text as output from reducer.

Comment: I see that we extends mapper, but then there is a function that takes in the actual types, as shown above. What role does <Text, Text, Text, Text> actually play. Is that seen as a parameter in Java?

Comment: I'm most confused as to why it's in there 4 time. Am I calling this class while passing in 4 "Text" objects?

Comment: You will notice that the [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html) also has the brackets to indicate they are generic types. It's like a "fill in the blank" for what types the other methods should have. If you look at the methods in the `Mapper` class, each generic type has a different role.

Comment: Generics were introduced in Java 1.5.  If you last used Java before then, that would explain why you don't recognize them.  See the [Generics chapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/) of [_The Java Tutorials_](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) for a gentle introduction, and Angelika Langer's [Java Generics FAQs](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) for all the _horrifying_ edge cases.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html) provides a very concise breakdown of it.

```
 public class Mapper<KEYIN,VALUEIN,KEYOUT,VALUEOUT>
```

For your example...

- `KEYIN` is `Object`
- `VALUEIN` is `Text`
- `KEYOUT` is `Text`
- `VALUEOUT` is `IntWritable`

I'm not versed in the ways of Hadoop, but if I had to hazard a guess, you accept a key of type `Object`, a value of type `Text`, and output a key of type `Text` and a value of type `IntWritable`.

The same would be true for a type bound by `<Text, Text, Text, Text>`, except *everything* - the keys and values - would be all `Text`.